# How to list/delete Cloudformation stack from a Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

In my application, I need to create resources from a given Cloudformation template.

There will be many stacks created from the same CloudFormation template.
And a schedule job will be triggered on a daily basis to remove the stacks created more than 1 day.

I plan to do this with a Lambda function (best to be in Python)
From [Setup Lambda function to run a CloudFormation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075343/setup-lambda-function-to-run-a-cloudformation-stack) I found a way to create stack from Lambda.

But may I know how to list/delete stacks from Lambda function, too?

Thanks.
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But may I know how to list/delete stacks from Lambda function, too?

In boto3 you can use the following functions:

- [list_stacks](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.list_stacks): Returns the summary information for stacks whose status matches the specified StackStatusFilte
- [delete_stack](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.delete_stack): Deletes a specified stack. Once the call completes successfully, stack deletion starts.